# Is there a way to make turtle-graphics object oriented?

Tags: python, oop, module, turtle-graphics

```
class Paddle(turtle.Turtle):
    def __init__(self, pos, color, shape, speed, shape_size):
        self.turtle.pos = turtle.goto(pos)
        self.turtle.color = turtle.color(color)
        self.turtle.shape = turtle.shape(shape)
        self.turtle.speed = turtle.speed(speed)
        self.turtle.shapesize = turtle.shapesize(shapesize)
```

**OOP Python turtle module**
I have tried to make my game object oriented by trying this code block above, but I get the **AttributeError: 'Paddle' object has no attribute 'turtle'** traceback. Honestly I have never done OOP with inheritance and modules combined so I'm not quite sure what I'm supposed to do. If you have a resource where I can learn how **inheritance works with modules**, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python turtle graphics is object-oriented.  The question is, "Is there a way to make your program object-oriented?"  We can implement the spirit of what your code is trying to do in an object-oriented fashion something like:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

class Paddle(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, position, color, shape, speed, stretch):
        super().__init__(shape=shape, visible=False)

        self.penup()
        self.goto(position)
        self.color(color)
        self.shape(shape)
        self.speed(speed)
        self.shapesize(stretch, 1)

        self.showturtle()

screen = Screen()

paddle1 = Paddle((100, 100), 'blue', 'square', 'fastest', 3)
paddle2 = Paddle((-100, 100), 'red', 'square', 'fastest', 3)

screen.exitonclick()
```

You were mixing the OOP concepts of ***isa*** and ***contains***.  The above solution only uses ***isa***

[image]